# Range.Find returns error Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I'm writing a sub that allows a user to input an ID number (QuickRef). I'm using range.find, but cannot find a way past the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed."

The dataset is dynamic, so I've built a way to identify the correct range to be searched as follows:

```
Dim qRef As String
Dim qCol As Byte
Dim lRow As Long
Dim subject As Range
Dim sRow As Long
Dim found As Range

'Finds the QuickRef column in the dataset
qCol = Cells.Find(What:="QuickRef", _
            After:=Range("DataDump"), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

'Finds the last row of the dataset
lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row

'Sets the range in which you will search for the QuickRef
Set qRef = Range(Range("DataDump").Offset(1, qCol - 2), Cells(lRow, qCol))

qRef.Select 'confirms the correct range is being referred to.

'error occurs with following line
sRow = Range(qRef).Find(What:=InputBox("Enter main subject QuickRef", "Subject Selection"), _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row

debug.print sRow
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I get past it?

Comment: What is qRef  please?

Comment: qRef is a range I defined previously that found a certain column header and its last row. It returns in this case R12:R1600.

Answer (score 2):

This is more by way of some other helpful observations

1) Include the sheet reference you are working with explicitly otherwise the Activesheet is used implicitly.

2) What you are looking for may not be found and then you won't have a .Row to access as the returned Range object will be Nothing. There should be a test for this.

```
Public Sub GetTotal()
    Dim sRow As Long
    Dim qRef As String
    Dim found As Range

    qRef = "A:A"
    Set found = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(qRef) & _
        .Find( _
            What:=InputBox("Enter main subject QuickRef", "Subject Selection"), _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)


    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        sRow = found.Row
    End If
    Debug.Print sRow
End Sub
```